# How to execute some code when gradle is building the tests

Tags: gradle, kotlin

Kotlin have a compiler plugin called [all open](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/compiler-plugins.html#all-open-compiler-plugin). It forces that all the classes with some annotations are open.

I want to use this feature for my tests but I don't want it in my production code (I want my classes closed). How can I do this?

I tried something like:

```
test {
  allOpen {
    annotation('com.my.Annotation')
  }
}
```

But the code is execute always.

Comment: But as long as this annotation is only used for your test classes, this isn't a problem, right? Anyway, I'm interested why you'd need that for tests?

Comment: The annotations are used to allow Mockito to mock my production code, so the annotations are in my production code :(. Why I need this? Because there're [some other ways](http://hadihariri.com/2016/10/04/Mocking-Kotlin-With-Mockito/) to mock closed classes but [they are really slow](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/1142).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It happens because the plugin is applied in the root of the `build.gradle` file.

A solution that will 100% work is to not apply the plugin unless some project property is set.

```
if (project.hasProperty("allopen")) {

  apply plugin: "kotlin-allopen"

  allOpen {
    annotation('com.my.Annotation')
  }

}
```

and run test with the property: `gradle -Pallopen test`.

Maybe some Gradle gurus can chime in with a better solution.

Comment: That's a good solution. :+1:
Another might be to reverse this condition. It will always be open by default and in your release scripts you can put the CLI argument to disable that make them final again.

Comment: I'm curious how can I add a property in Android Studio configuration.

Answer (score 7):

I think, that you can do so:

```
android.applicationVariants.all { ApplicationVariant variant ->
    boolean hasTest = gradle.startParameter.taskNames.find {it.contains("test") || it.contains("Test")} != null
    if (hasTest) {
        apply plugin: 'kotlin-allopen'
        allOpen {
            annotation('com.my.Annotation')
        }
    }
}
```

Then you will not need to pass a property when running the test.

Comment: You don't need `ApplicationVariant` but otherwise I find this to be the best solution. Thanks!

Comment: I added `ApplicationvVariant` for IDE to prompt all properties of variant. You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly same issue - wanted to have opened classes only for tests because of mocking. I didn't want to use custom parameter, because the code is running locally, on CI and therefore would need to be setup everywhere.

Found solution for it - checking whether task name contains `test`:

```
def isTestTask = getGradle().getStartParameter().getTaskNames().any {name -> name.contains("test")}

if (isTestTask) {
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-allopen'
    allOpen {
        annotation('com.my.Annotation')
    }
}
```

You may try if it would suit you better :)

Comment: any specific why it's not working? Do you have the annotation properly set?

Comment: Maybe it was the syntax. I tried using the syntax from p.alexey's answer and it worked :)